# Making printer web-accessible

Tags: printing

I operate a small co-working space within a University and am having some challenges with printing.  The University uses a print release system on its network which is not accessible to users of the co-working space who all use the guest WiFi (with no associated printers).  I want to set up a printer that is accessible to them without having to either manually plug in via USB or change to a different WiFi network to access it.  The solution I'm envisaging would effectively give the printer a URL that users could add and print from anywhere.  I can source a raspberry pi/mini PC etc to act as a print server.

I had initially looked at CRUPS with Balena on a raspberry Pi but the printer and device need to be on the same network.  I'm aware of Papercut PrintMobility but remote printing doesn't work from Macs at the moment.  ezeep looks promising but it's fairly expensive.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to go about this?

Many thanks!

Comment: When you say "printer and device" need to be on the same network", are you referring to the user PCs? I'm not aware of any such restriction in CUPS, where did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, "Web-accessible" and "network-accessible" are two different things. There are several network protocols for remote printing, but most of them are independent TCP/IP-based protocols running on their own ports (e.g. LPD uses TCP 515 and JetDirect uses TCP 9100).

So if by "web" you mean that your guest Wi-Fi clients are limited to HTTP and HTTPS, then the IPP protocol is probably your best choice, as it is practically HTTP-based – although it does run over port 631 by default, but there's no problem in switching that to port 80, and the secure IPPS already shares port 443 with HTTPS. (Besides that, IPP is currently becoming the default network-printing protocol in general, with initiatives such as "IPP Everywhere" for driverless printing.)

The Linux printing system CUPS can be used as a server for IPP and IPPS. These are enabled by default – all you have to do is open it up to non-localhost clients. (It also comes with 'cups-lpd' for serving LPD, which might be more convenient for Windows clients.)

Most operating systems support IPP printing – macOS uses IPP as its primary printing protocol (AirPrint is IPP-based), Windows also has a built-in IPP client installable through "Turn Windows features on and off" ([instructions](https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/InstallingIPPSPrinters)), and Linux clients have the same CUPS.

Comment: Many thanks for the info. I'd been looking specifically at an implementation of CUPS using balena cloud and it seems its the latter that limits things to the local network. I'll do some research on IPP!